# How can I save html canvas and then reload it without loosing the shapes?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, save, shapes

I have an html5 canvas to which user can add shapes. shapes have all kind of behaviors - they are resizable, they can be moved around, etc.
I need to save it, so I can reload later (user added shapes,saved, closed the browser. when he reopens the browser, he should get the same canvas with the shapes as he saved them before. he should be able to move/resize the exisiting shapes and to add new ones)

toDataURL is not good for me, because it converts canvas with all the shapes to an  image, so all the existing shapes are lost.
Is there some way to save the canvas or maybe the context as an object to the db and reload it later?

Comment: You can get canvas serialization out of the box with canvas library like [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could store the attributes of each shape in a `JSON` object, and store that in `localStorage` or save it to the DB. Something like this:

```
var ShapeData = {shapes:[]}
for(var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {

    var newShape = {
        type : shapes[i].getType(),
        x : shapes[i].getX(),
        y : shapes[i].getY(),
        w : shapes[i].getWidth(),
        h : shapes[i].getHeight(),
        rot : shapes[i].getRotation()
    }

    ShapeData.shapes[i] = newShape;
}


var toTheDatabase = JSON.stringify(ShapeData);
```

Would look like this:

```
var ShapeData = {
    "shapes" : [{
        "type":"square",
        "x":"10",
        "y":"40",
        "w":"2",
        "h":"90",
        "rot":"140"
    },{
       "type":"circle",
        "x":"60",
        "y":"100",
        "w":"2",
        "h":"90",
        "rot":"0"
    }]
}
```